# Java EE servlet as spring bean proxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have servlet named com.sample.servlets.CreateReleaseServlet for which I am trying to add spring AOP advice in a helper method.

I have the following code in spring config file:

```
<bean id="customerService" class="com.sample.servlets.CreateReleaseServlet">
</bean>

<bean id="notificationAdvice" class="com.sample.advice.NotificationAdvice" />

<bean id="customerServiceProxy" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">

    <property name="target" ref="customerService" />

    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>notificationAdvice</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

When I try to get this servlet as bean by using the following Java code:

```
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
        new String[] { "/WEB-INF/form-servlet.xml" });
CreateReleaseServlet servlet = (CreateReleaseServlet) appContext.getBean("customerServiceProxy");

String next = servlet.execute(req);
```

I get the following exception:

```
 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[CreateReleaseServlet]: java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy103 incompatible with com.sample.servlets.CreateReleaseServlet
        at com.sample.servlets.CreateReleaseServlet.service(CreateReleaseServlet.java:1823)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1229)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
        at com.sample.servlets.SampleFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3751)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1690)
```

Any suggestion will be of great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have enabled proxying of classes (and not plain JdkProxy of interfaces), this will not work, as the proxy object will not act as a subclass of your servlet. You could probably cast it to an instance of `Servlet` instead. That said, your approach does seem a little strange. What do your interceptor do? The common way of doing AOP(ish) stuff with servlets is to create a servlet filter. And if that's not an option, I suggest you convert your servlet to a Spring MVC controller and use regular Spring MVC options for configuring interceptors.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. You saved me from lot of trouble. For the time being, what I have done is : 1) Create an interface with the methods which I am invoking from service method of servlet (execute method in my case) 2) Make the servlet implement this interface 3) Modify the getBean call to work with the new interface. 4) Call execute method on interface. Again it wouldn't have been possible without your reply. I have read that it is possible to avoid interfaces by using CGLib .http://insufficientinformation.blogspot.in/2007/12/spring-dynamic-proxies-vs-cglib-proxies.html

Comment: Great! :) But I would consider refactoring it into a servlet filter or a Spring MVC controller eventually.